# Retrieving data from thingspeak website to HelloCharts

Tags: java, android

In this code data is taken from thingspeak website given the channel id. the channel is public. The graph is obtained using hellocharts and chartview.

QUESTION:
I want to print all the data values which are plotted on the graph or the last data added in a text view. In which variable is the data stored As i want to further work with the data.

[image: For the output please see the link]

In the output I want to know that the value 395 is stored in which variable.

I have provided the java code below.

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.ThingSpeakChannel;
import com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.ThingSpeakLineChart;
import com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.ChannelFeed;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import lecho.lib.hellocharts.model.LineChartData;
import lecho.lib.hellocharts.model.Viewport;
import lecho.lib.hellocharts.view.LineChartView;

public class DemoActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private ThingSpeakChannel tsChannel;
private ThingSpeakLineChart tsChart;
private LineChartView chartView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Connect to ThinkSpeak Channel 9
    tsChannel = new ThingSpeakChannel(135855);
    // Set listener for Channel feed update events
    tsChannel.setChannelFeedUpdateListener(new ThingSpeakChannel.ChannelFeedUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChannelFeedUpdated(long channelId, String channelName, ChannelFeed channelFeed) {
            // Show Channel ID and name on the Action Bar
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(channelName);
            getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("Channel " + channelId);
            // Notify last update time of the Channel feed through a Toast message
            Date lastUpdate = channelFeed.getChannel().getUpdatedAt();
            Toast.makeText(DemoActivity.this, lastUpdate.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    // Fetch the specific Channel feed
    tsChannel.loadChannelFeed();

    // Create a Calendar object dated 5 minutes ago
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -5);

    // Configure LineChartView
    chartView = (LineChartView) findViewById(R.id.chart);
    chartView.setZoomEnabled(false);
    chartView.setValueSelectionEnabled(true);

    // Create a line chart from Field1 of ThinkSpeak Channel 9
    tsChart = new ThingSpeakLineChart(135855, 2);
    // Get 200 entries at maximum
    tsChart.setNumberOfEntries(200);
    // Set value axis labels on 10-unit interval
    tsChart.setValueAxisLabelInterval(10);
    // Set date axis labels on 5-minute interval
    tsChart.setDateAxisLabelInterval(10);
    // Show the line as a cubic spline
    tsChart.useSpline(true);
    // Set the line color
    tsChart.setLineColor(Color.parseColor("#D32F2F"));
    // Set the axis color
    tsChart.setAxisColor(Color.parseColor("#455a64"));
    // Set the starting date (5 minutes ago) for the default viewport of the chart
   // tsChart.setChartStartDate(calendar.getTime());
    // Set listener for chart data update
    tsChart.setListener(new ThingSpeakLineChart.ChartDataUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChartDataUpdated(long channelId, int fieldId, String title, LineChartData lineChartData, Viewport maxViewport, Viewport initialViewport) {
            // Set chart data to the LineChartView
            chartView.setLineChartData(lineChartData);
            // Set scrolling bounds of the chart
            chartView.setMaximumViewport(maxViewport);
            // Set the initial chart bounds
            chartView.setCurrentViewport(initialViewport);
           /* LineChartData data = new LineChartData();
            float data1=data.getBaseValue();
            TextView tvName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
            tvName.setText((int) data1);*/

        }
    });
    // Load chart data asynchronously
    tsChart.loadChartData();
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing where you even obtain X and Y values for the chart... `tsChart.loadChartData();` - what is that doing?

Comment: Looking at the source code of `ThingSpeakLineChart`, it does not expose that information

Answer (score 0):

According to the [HelloCharts source-code](https://github.com/lecho/hellocharts-android/tree/master/hellocharts-library), I believe you are looking for [this method](https://github.com/lecho/hellocharts-android/blob/master/hellocharts-library/src/lecho/lib/hellocharts/view/LineChartView.java#L43) after the chart data has been asynchronously loaded.

```
chartView.getLineChartData()
```

And from that, you should be able to get down to a `Line` object, and `line.getValues()` holds the data you want as a [`List<PointValue>`](https://github.com/lecho/hellocharts-android/blob/master/hellocharts-library/src/lecho/lib/hellocharts/model/PointValue.java)

All in all,

```
List<PointValue> values = chartView.getLineChartData().getLines().getValues();
// TODO: for (PointValue p : values) { p.getX(); p.getY(); }
```

This list contains a [`PointValue`](https://github.com/lecho/hellocharts-android/blob/master/hellocharts-library/src/lecho/lib/hellocharts/model/PointValue.java) class with `getX` and `getY` methods

Comment: Can you please provide the code to declare line object? And line.getvalues() will return a string?

Comment: I haven't used that library. I'm purely reading the source code on Github. Android Studio should even auto complete these methods so you'll see what is being returned

Comment: Can you provide the github link from which you are referring the source code

Comment: I an getting an error in .getValues() in the line List<PointValue> values = chartView.getLineChartData().getLines().getValues();  on auto correcting it adds API index but stills there is an error.

Comment: A runtime error or compile time error? I never guaranteed it would return data, but that is the chain of methods you need. You might need to check for null values and such

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about this particular library but to access your data you could simply hit the API of your given channel i.e.

```
String lightApi = "https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/<your_channel_id>/fields/<field_number>.json?api_key=<read_API_key>&results=<number_of_readings>";

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,lightApi, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            JSONArray feeds = response.getJSONArray("feeds");
            for(int i=0; i<feeds.length();i++){
                JSONObject jo = feeds.getJSONObject(i);
                String l=jo.getString("<your_field_number>"); //you may want to Integer.parseInt the returned value
                //String date=jo.getString("created_at"); -->to get the date and time
                // Do whatever you want to do with each of these values...
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```